# rsyslog has "great" latency when writing to local log file

Tags: python-3.x, bash, rsyslog

I'm using rsyslog to write logs on a Raspberry Pi, with a standard */etc/rsyslog.conf* file.
Im writing logs from Bash scripts using the **logger** command and from Python scripts using the **syslog** library.

Bash Example:

```
logger --tag=currentFile.sh --priority=local0.warn "Some error message"
```

Python Example:

```
syslog.openlog(ident="currentFile.py", facility=syslog.LOG_LOCAL0)      # create syslog handle
syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_WARNING, "Some error message"                  # write error message
```

To prepare for future logging to a remote rsyslog server, the "local0.log" file is used as a central log file.

The logging works just fine, but i can't figure out, why the logs always have a delay of 1-5 minutes. This especially occurs when i do error handling inside a python script and then write a log to "local0.log".

I'm asking because i can't think of a reason why local logging could have such a big latency. Maybe it is something to do with the **syslog** python library i use?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested...
I managed to solve the issue.

### Observation

---

The problem didn't lie with the python *syslog* library and neither with the bash *logger* command.

> Rsyslog gathers log messages and adds them to the main queue. A worker thread then pulls messages off the main queue and delivers them to their desinations and/or adds the message to an action queue. If a worker is **unable** to deliver messages to a destination, all progress of that queue will block until that delivery is able to succeed (or hits the retry limit and permanently fails).

So the message wasn't written for a few minutes or got entirely "deleted", because rsyslog tried to establish a connection with a server that wasn't responding.

### The Solution

---

This is a snippet of my */etc/rsyslog.conf* before:

```
# local file:
local0.*          /var/log/local0.log

# Syslog over TCP:
local0.*          @@192.100.100.100
```

*/etc/rsyslog.conf* now:

```
action(name="someName" type="omfwd" Target="192.100.100.100" Port="50514" 
    Protocol="tcp" queue.type="FixedArray"

# local file:
local0.*          /var/log/local0.log
```

This will create an action queue which won't block all log processing if the connection fails. Of course there is a bit more to it, to then deliver it to the server, but then i'd have to get into *modules* which would be too big for this post.

### Note

---

If you have further questions on rsyslog, its queues and workers, check out this "[guide](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/login/articles/06_lang.pdf)" by David Lang, it really helped me understand how rsyslog works.